# libGDX texturepacker rotation

Tags: java, android, rotation, libgdx

I'm using TexturePackerPro program for packing sprites in to .pack file and use it in libGDX.
On some sprites there is  `rotate: true` flag but when I read sprite in libgdx sprite is not rotated.

```
  rotate: true
  xy: 425, 1066
  size: 59, 96
  orig: 59, 96
  offset: 0, 0
  index: -1
```

Why sprite didn't rotate it self when rotate flag is set to true ? If I must to rotate manually when drawing, then why there is rotate flag?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The sprite isn't rotated because libgdx is rotating your texture region back to its original rotation.

Why?  The rotate flag is there just to tell how the texture in the pack file is oriented, not how you want your image oriented after the region is loaded.  Libgdx assumes you want all images oriented upright.

Comment: what should I do to display region with proper rotation? thanks

Comment: Iterate over all `AtlasRegion` in your `TextureAtlas`.  If an `AtlasRegion` rotate is true, rotate that region clockwise 90 degrees, and swap the width and height. This should work for you.

You could try just deleting the rotate line in your pack file, but you'd have to do this every time.

Comment: How exactly do you rotate the region 90 degrees clockwise, there doesn't seem to be a method to do that?

Comment: You'd need to create a new texture at runtime. This texture would need to be recreated each time OpenGL context was lost (could be slow.)

Comment: So the best solution is to pack the textures with rotation option disabled I suppose?

Comment: libgdx does not automatically unrotate it for you. You need to do it manually in your code. Possibly you can use flip at runtime?

Comment: if you lose the opengl context the time to reload a texure is pretty insignificant since the it was lost probably due to a "user world" interruption amounting to seconds if not minutes. A few ms to restart wont matter,

Comment: @WilliamMorrison I have the same issue and I think the question is why the sprite is not rotating back automatically at runtime when the flag is set to true. The original rotation is not the one I see in the packed file.

Comment: @NiiLaryea `AtlasRegion` doesn't have a rotation method but `AtlasSprite` does.

Answer (score -1):

You have to use `Sprite` or `AtlasSprite` to get the rotation properties. `TextureRegion` or `AtlasRegion` doesn't consider rotation. If you are converting it into a `Drawable`, use `SpriteDrawable`.